# ffmpeg audio decode data is zero

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I tried to decode the audio using ffmpeg with the following code:

```
NSMutableData *finalData = [NSMutableData data];
......
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0){
    if(packet.stream_index == videoStream)
    {
        int consumed = avcodec_decode_audio4(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_frame_ptr, &packet);

        if(got_frame_ptr)
        {
            [finalData appendBytes:(pFrame->data)[0] length:(pFrame->linesize)[0]];

        }
    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
......
[finalData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Bu the saved file can't be played, even I changed the file extension to wav. When I look into it in HexEdit (a Hex editor), I found there are many zero bytes. For example the content of the file before offset 0x970 are all zero. Is there any error in my code? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the decode result is good. The zero bytes in the file is normal, because the decode result is PCM data. I tried to import the data into Adobe Audition, it can be played. FYI.